# SQL Command text is not collected by App Insights for web app running on Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-application-insights

Followed [standard installation guide from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-cloudservices)

- Checked "Send diagnostics data to Application Insights" in role properties and published the app to CS - no request data collected at all.
- Added SDK to the project and re-uploaded the app - got request data, but all SQL Dependencies collected with totally useless "Command Text" - "server name | database name".

However, SQL Command are traced for the same app on my local IIS if Azure Status Monitor is installed.

I connected to the server via RDP and it seems that AI Status Monitor is installed successfully by Azure PaaS Diagnostics plugin, but not registered as COR_PROFILER for W3SVC, so it actually do nothing.

Is there any specific configuration switch exists to enable full SQL command tracing for cloud services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that enabling "Send diagnostics data to Application Insights" and adding SDK to the project *should* be enough to collect dependency data.

However, current installer of Status Monitor included in Azure Cloud Service PaaS Diagnostics Plugin v1.10.1.1 is *broken*. I tried installer from previous version of plugin (v.1.10.0.0) - and it works perfectly.

Running \StatusMonitor\ApplicationInsightsAgent.msi from latest version of plugin logs the following exception:

```
Calling custom action CustomActions!CustomActions.CustomActions.SetEnvironmentVariables
Error: could not load custom action class CustomActions.CustomActions from assembly: CustomActions
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'CustomActions, Version=2.4.0.18059, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
File name: 'CustomActions, Version=2.4.0.18059, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
```

I unpacked that CustomActions.dll and checked strong name for it via sn.

```
sn.exe -vf CustomActions.dll

CustomActions.dll is a delay-signed or test-signed assembly
```

Same check for CustomActions.dll from v1.10.0.0 shows

```
Assembly 'CustomActions.dll' is valid
```

Apparently, someone in MS forgot to sign that dll before release, so Status Monitor is no longer correctly installed on CS VMs. Reported that to MS Support, hope they will fix that soon.

---

A workaround could be manually adding missing registry key on role start, while W3SVC is not started yet:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC\@Environment
```

of type Multi-String Value with value

```
COR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1
COR_PROFILER={324F817A-7420-4E6D-B3C1-143FBED6D855}
MicrosoftInstrumentationEngine_Host={CA487940-57D2-10BF-11B2-A3AD5A13CBC0}
```

Raw reg file is:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC]
"Environment"=hex(7):43,00,4f,00,52,00,5f,00,45,00,4e,00,41,00,42,00,4c,00,45,\
  00,5f,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,4c,00,49,00,4e,00,47,00,3d,00,31,00,\
  00,00,43,00,4f,00,52,00,5f,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,4c,00,45,00,52,\
  00,3d,00,7b,00,33,00,32,00,34,00,46,00,38,00,31,00,37,00,41,00,2d,00,37,00,\
  34,00,32,00,30,00,2d,00,34,00,45,00,36,00,44,00,2d,00,42,00,33,00,43,00,31,\
  00,2d,00,31,00,34,00,33,00,46,00,42,00,45,00,44,00,36,00,44,00,38,00,35,00,\
  35,00,7d,00,00,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,49,\
  00,6e,00,73,00,74,00,72,00,75,00,6d,00,65,00,6e,00,74,00,61,00,74,00,69,00,\
  6f,00,6e,00,45,00,6e,00,67,00,69,00,6e,00,65,00,5f,00,48,00,6f,00,73,00,74,\
  00,3d,00,7b,00,43,00,41,00,34,00,38,00,37,00,39,00,34,00,30,00,2d,00,35,00,\
  37,00,44,00,32,00,2d,00,31,00,30,00,42,00,46,00,2d,00,31,00,31,00,42,00,32,\
  00,2d,00,41,00,33,00,41,00,44,00,35,00,41,00,31,00,33,00,43,00,42,00,43,00,\
  30,00,7d,00,00,00,00,00
```

Answer (score 1):

In [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now), we can find that if only the Application Insights SDK is added to web app project, the Dependencies diagnostics will not collect SQL command text by default.

[image]

And according to your description, [installing Application Insights Status Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now#monitor-a-live-iis-web-app) seems not help collect SQL command text. If possible, you can try to  [write code to send dependency information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-dependencies#custom-dependency-tracking) using `TrackDependency`, the following code works for me, please refer to it.

```
var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("{connect_string}");

    commendtext = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.AspNetUsers";

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(commendtext, con);

    con.Open();

    int n = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();

    con.Close();

    success = n > 0 ? true : false;

}
finally
{
    timer.Stop();
    telemetry.TrackDependency("SQL", "SQL: tcp:{server_name}.database.windows.net,1433 | {database_name}", ":{server_name}.database.windows.net", commendtext, startTime, timer.Elapsed, "{result_code}", success);
}
```

***Details SQL command text on Application Insights portal***

[image]

Comment: Installing status monitor helps on my local machine. Status monitor is also installed on the cloud service VM by azure infrastructure, but that setup seems to be incomplete. Manual instrumentation of entire app just because of some incomplete installation of status monitor will require quite a lot of work and will not help with queries done via EF :(

Comment: traced the issue down to bad installer of Status Monitor used by MS to pre-configure Cloud Service, posted possible workaround as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i get the commandtext (without code or any change) was using status monitor v2, enabling instrumentation manually and adding -connectionstring instead of -instrumentationkey or -instrumentationkeymap.

```
Install status monitor v2
Enable-ApplicationInsightsMonitoring (using -connectionstring, cannot get working using -instrumentationkey)
Enable-InstrumentationEngine
Restart iis (auto)
```

Also if webserver, server or application is re-deployed it will stop showing the commandtext.