# Application Insights Codeless attach Status Monitor V2

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, dependencies, azure-application-insights

im using Application Insight Codeless Attach over IIS with Status Monitor v2.

Everything works great, the only thing is that im not able to see SQL CommandText over the insights.

> In addition to the platform specific steps above, you must also
> explicitly opt-in to enable SQL command collection by modifying the
> applicationInsights.config file with the following:

The application folder does not have any applicationInsights.config file so is not possible to add the following:

```
<EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation>true</EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation>
```

I've also tried to change the ApplicationInsights-default.config and ApplicationInsights-recommended.config files under "ApplicationMonitor\version\content\runtime" without success.

Does somebody know how to add this property without code implementation?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46427347/sql-command-text-is-not-collected-by-app-insights-for-web-app-running-on-cloud-s

Comment: It looks that only works when -connectionstring is used at the moment status monitor is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

As this doc mentioned, IIS server need to use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient`.

> requires using the instrumentation engine or by using the
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient NuGet package instead of the
> System.Data.SqlClient library

[image]

===========================Test result=====================

I created a test asp.net core mvc app and used `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, after deploying to azure web app and enable application insights, I can see sql query text like below.

[image]

Comment: I get it working without using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and without a single line of code in the application. Just using status monitor v2, enabling instrumentation and adding -connectionstring instead of -instrumentationkey or -instrumentationkeymap. The problem with this approach is  that when you deploy an app looks like the instrumentation service stop getting the sqlcommandtext until you restart it

Comment: Ok, that's fine : )

Answer (score 0):

I get it working without using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and without a single line of code in the application. Just using status monitor v2, enabling instrumentation and adding -connectionstring instead of -instrumentationkey or -instrumentationkeymap. The problem with this approach is that when you deploy an app looks like the instrumentation service stop getting the sqlcommandtext until you restart it –